# "blunder/work/inch/push/sneak my way into/across/through/out of" – in Russian

Tags: перевод

> 1) I've somehow managed to **blunder my way into** a management position.
>
> = Я как-то умудрился (???) ...

In English, we often use the structure "verb of motion + one's way + preposition" such as:

> 2) I've been so fortunate to **work my way up to** where I am now.
>
> 3) We **inched our way across** the room, hardly daring to breathe.
>
> 4) I'm not too keen on travelling to Prague, as the thought of **pushing my way through** a crowd of tourists doesn't exactly appeal to me.
>
> 5) I **sneaked my way out of** the office earlier than usual.

I wonder if there is some fixed structure in Russian  roughly corresponding to this English construction. How do Russian speakers commonly express these ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think a full equivalent exists. Here's how I would render your examples:

> I've somehow managed to blunder my way into a management position.

Каким-то образом я умудрился **оказаться** в начальниках.

OR: Меня каким-то образом занесло в начальники.

> I've been so fortunate to **work my way up to** where I am now.

Мне повезло **доработать до** моей текущей должности.

> We **inched our way across** the room, hardly daring to breathe.

**Мало-помалу** мы **протиснулись на другой конец** комнаты, едва дыша.

> ...pushing my way through a crowd ...

толкаться в толпе / расталкивать толпу

> I **sneaked my way out of** the office earlier than usual.

Я **улизнул из** офиса раньше обычного.

One can also replace **улизнул** with the colloquial **слинял**.

There is the expression **проложить себе дорогу/путь чем-либо** but it's too bookish:

- Сын ремесленника, он начал службу с должности писца и **упорным трудом проложил себе путь к** вершинам немецкой почтовой иерархии.
- Смело, товарищи, в ногу, 
  Духом окрепнем в борьбе 
  В царство свободы **дорогу 

  Грудью проложим** себе

Comment: 1) also пробиться (в начальникИ)

Comment: i think 2) is misconstrued, it's about career rather than tenure (which is connoted by доработать), so my translation would be дорасти до

Comment: I'd say that "слинял" is more daring and less sneaky than "улизнул".

Comment: @Alissa Hi. As you noted, the "sneak my way out" in this context is not so much about "**tiptoeing** my way out" as about "rather boldly shirking". So is "слинять" better suited?

Comment: in 2) besides дорасти до also дослужиться до fits well, but the verb itself isn't very popular nowadays, unfortunately, perhaps because semantic link of the word *служба* with job is all but lost

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens I think so, yes.